# How to play back a DAT file which is recorded by demo_recording (ADTF)

Tags: adtf, adtf3

I use the ADTF GUI Control to start demo_recording and to record a DAT file.

What is the easiest way to play back this DAT file? Is there a minimum configuration to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to adapt the playback_example for that, because the streams of the adtfdat files are different.

1. Open Configuration Editor
2. Choose the playback example
3. Go to Streaming Graph, right-click on the player and Edit Properties
4. Set your recorded adtfdat file to the filename property of the player and connect the stream to the Sample Streams
5. Save and start the playback example